# why is #comment syntax not allowed in erb's <%= %>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3. I had tried to add #comment in <%= %>, and it turned out that it's not valid...and error raised... My code is:

```
<%= @page_title || 'Pragmatic Bookshelf' #magic @page_title; a if a is true, else b%>
```

It seems ok putting #comment into <% %> without the equal sign in it. My question is: why is that?

Also, how do you put comment inside <%= %>?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A `#comment` runs to the end of a line, but the use of `=` is rewritten as a function call, like `puts()`

If we rewrite

```
<%= @page_title || 'Pragmatic Bookshelf' #magic @page_title; a if a is true, else b%>
```

as

```
puts(@page_title || 'Pragmatic Bookshelf' #magic @page_title; a if a is true, else b)
```

It becomes clear that the closing parenthesis `)` is part of the comment, and therefore the statement can't be parsed correctly.

To work around this, we can just use a separate ERB comment block, like so:

```
<%= @page_title || 'Pragmatic Bookshelf' %><%# magic @page_title; a if a is true, else b%>
```

As a final note, using the `||` operator to coalesce nil variables is a very common Ruby idiom, and does not need a comment at all.  As Steve McConnell says in *Code Complete*, comments should explain why something is done, not how something is done.

Comment: oh, thanks for the final note. but my case is I just start  learning rails for 1 day only when I wrote this code... I promise i'm not gonna do that later... :)

Comment: another question: why <% concat(csrf_meta_tag) #aa%> is invalid while <% javascript_include_tag :defaults #abc%> is valid?

Comment: Is it possible that `concat` is not defined? Usually it's called on a String, such as `"Hello".concat(", world!")`

Comment: it's a method in rails's TextHelpers, see at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat